# How to access nested arrays of different (unknown) lengths in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a system that's using nested arrays of different lengths. For example, I have:

```
$this->parentArray['level1'][1]['associative_key_1']
```

as well as

```
$this->parentArray['level1']['associative_key_1'] //no middle index [1]
```

I'm trying to dynamically access these nested arrays but I'm having trouble. This is what I'm trying:

```
public function getArray($arrayPath){
    $theArray = explode('.', $arrayPath); //arrayPath is in dot notation coming from JS
    $theTag = "";
    foreach ($theArray as $a) {   
        $theTag .= "['" . $a . "']";
    }
    $theBase = 'parentArray'.$theTag;
    print($this->$theBase);
}
```

This successfully constructs what appears to be a string in the format that I want...something like `parentArray['level1']['1']['associative_key_1']` and also it works if there's an array with fewer nests. So if I print `$theBase` no problem and everything seems fine. but if I try to use it in a dynamic variable and access the property in the class such as `$this->$theBase` it throws an error saying the property is not found. but if I go and type the array path manually, it does in fact exist.

How can I dynamically build/access a nested array with unknown lengths?

Comment: Make the source data in well format.

Comment: what do you mean? what is "well format"?

Comment: With same structure.

Comment: Has same length

Comment: that can't work for my project. the whole thing is built around these arrays and they're all different lengths.